# LESS CSS - Adding a percentage to a hex color - How does this work?

Tags: css, less

Let's say there is a LESS variable representing a CSS color in hex

```
@primary-color: #0070B8;
```

Somewhere else in the LESS code, @primary-color is operated on like this.

```
@new-color: @primary-color + 10%;
```

@new-color is #0a7ac2.

**How did LESS derive the new color?**  I tried looking at rgb and hsl versions of **the @primary-color versus the @new-color**, but I don't see the values being a 10% difference in any scale.  It looks like it added an absolute value of 10 to the **R/G/B component** of the hex color, but that seems counter-intuitive. (I presume SASS works similarly.)

```
#0070B8
0,112,184
(0,112,184)
rgb(0,112,184)
rgb(0%,44%,72%)
hsl(203° 100% 36%)

#0a7ac2
10,122,194
(10,122,194)
rgb(10,122,194)
rgb(4%,48%,76%)
203° 90% 40%
```

(EDIT: I didn't write this LESS code.  I saw it in a repo, and I was trying to figure how this worked, because I couldn't find anything in the LESS documentation that explained the percentage when it's used in a + operation.  Bolded text was added by another user.)

Comment: Why a close vote for this?

Comment: Found a quote somewhere "LESS provides a variety of functions that transform colors. Colors are first converted to the HSL color-space, and then manipulated at the channel level. All color operations take a color and a percentage as parameters, except spin, which uses integers between 0 and 255 instead of percentages to modify the hue, and mix, which takes two colors as parameters." ...and this link [**LESS Color Functions**](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations)

Comment: Just in case, if you really need to add (per-rgb-channel)`10%` of a color to the color itself in Less it's `@color + @color * 0.1` that in its turn can be simplified to `@color * 1.1`.

Comment: @Paulie_D: That documentation refers to LESS's color functions.  My question is about using the + operator on a hex color.  That's why I also generated the hsl and rgb values in my example.   If LESS were using 10% of the hsl or rgb values, the values I provided in my question should work out, but it doesn't.  I found an example with the + operator, it doesn't talk about adding a percentage, so that's why I am asking.  http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I saw this code in an existing repo, so I wasn't sure how this worked.   But thanks for that idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Language Features > Overview > Operations](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations).

Assuming it's actually `@new-color: @primary-color + 10%;` (and `=` is just a typo in your Q) it goes like this:

- if the first operand of an arithmetic expression is a color any subsequent operands are converted to colors too.
- scalar numeric values (e.g. `10%`) are converted to a color as `value` -> `rgb(value, value, value)`. I.e. `10%` is converted to `rgb(10, 10, 10)` color value (`%` is irrelevant in this case and it will be the same for `10`, `10px`, `10whatever` etc.)
- arithmetic operations apply to color operands on a per-RGB-channel basis.

So in summary it's:

```css
#0070b8 -> rgb(0, 112, 184)
10%     -> rgb(10, 10, 10)

rgb(0, 112, 184) + rgb(10, 10, 10) ->
rgb(0 + 10, 112 + 10, 184 + 10) ->
rgb(10, 122, 194)

rgb(10, 122, 194) -> #0a7ac2
```

Or yet in other words, `#0070B8 + 10` is a just shorthand for `#0070b8 + #0a0a0a` hence the `#0a7aC2` result. (And yet again `%` unit has no effect there and should be removed to make it less confusing).

---

To answer:

> It looks like it added an absolute value of 10 to the R/G/B component of the hex color, but that seems counter-intuitive.

See [Strict Units](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-units).
Basically it is the same as `10px + 10%` for example, it will result in `20px` (and not in `10px + 10px * 0.1`). Same way CSS `calc(10px + 10%)` is not equal to `(10px + 10px * 0.1)` though Less arithmetic expressions are not equal to those of `calc` too since the compiler has no all that information about current element state a browser has.

Yes, `%` arithmetic is a typical confusion in Less, but note that percentage values in CSS *always* refer to a value set elsewhere and are never considered to be some kind of "ratio value" on their own. E.g. `width: 50%` -> `50% of the container width` and it's not equal to `width: 0.5` or something. So in Less you never assume `10%` in an arithmetic expression can refer to some previous value of the same expression and/or being implicitly converted to a unitless ratio (e.g. it's never `10%` -> `0.1`).

Comment: The URL to "Strict Units" goes to a 404.  I went to the LESS website, and I can't seem to find this entry.  However, the rest of your answer is golden.  That should have been put into the docs. Thank you.

Comment: @Stephen Fixed now. (Note though that `--su=on` won't have any effect in this case - it's seems like just not implementend  for colors, so I linked to it only in regards of the description of using different units in the same arithm expr).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  I'm very familiar with percentages used on CSS font size and widths/heights, since I use those often.  However, I've only used percentages on rgb or hsla color syntaxes.  Doing "math" directly on colors, however, was completely foreign to me (I don't think it's possible in CSS2; maybe CSS3 has native support).  Again, thanks for the answer.  I wish I could give you more SO karma for the answer.

Comment: @Stephen They plan [this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color-4/#modifying-colors) in CSS4 (though in its current state the syntax is just incredibly insane - I hope they'll make it more humane before standardization :). As soon as the spec. is released it won't be a big problem to implement the same stuff in Less.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see how LESS were inspired to get their color function names.  It looks like they are trying to stay in sync with future proposed standards.  Always a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

I actually think it just added `10` to each RGB value, because... `10%` of what? My guess is that it just used `10` instead of `10%`.

What you probably actually want is to use [`lighten(#0070B8, 10%)`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-lighten) which would add 10% (of 255 I think) to each RGB component of the color.

---

Side note, there are other "math-like" things in LESS that are strange like that too. For example, `10px + 10em` is a value that can't be calculated, so I believe it will just add `10+10` and give it the first unit of measure,which would result in `20px`.

Comment: Just in case, no, `lighten(#0070B8, 10%)` won't add `10% of 255` to each `RGB` component. `lighten` just adds `10%` to the `L` channel of a color in the `HSL` space.

Answer (score 0):

`rgb(0,112,184)`
`rgb(10,122,194)`

Seems you have used the syntax incorrectly. You should have used

```
lighten(#******, 10%);
```

or

```
darken(#******, 10%);
```

And so on. Incorrect Syntax has just resulted in LESS adding 10 to each RGB value